# How to add to ContextMenuStrip and ToolStrip same ToolStripButtons?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip, toolstripbutton, toolstripmenu

I have tool bar in my app and context menu with the same options, so I want to
add ToolStripButtons to both ContextMenuStrip and ToolStrip, unfortunately I can't do this.
Even when I add manually items to both it shows only on one.

For now I have buttons in tool bar:

[image]

I want something like this. I want this options to be one, because I will be often enable and disable this buttons and finally there is one option so why two buttons?

[image]

Comment: if the menua aren't dynamic you could simply build the 2 separatly and than make a fonction to syncronize them

Comment: I just make items Disable manually: toolStripItem1.Disabled = true; contextStripItem1.Disabled = true; for all items I have, for now.

Comment: then I don't really see to problem. you can still make the equivalent button have the same eventhandler so both will do the same thing

Comment: Yes, I know but both has same name, same image, same behavior so I'm thinking that should be same button. but If it is not possible, I just repeat every disable, enable, visible etc. for both.

Comment: It's not possible. A control can't be in two places at once. You really have no option but to double up. This is quite common.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem and I've found the easiest solution is to place the 'shared' code inside a `MenuFeature` class that inherits from `ToolStripMenuItem`.

You still have to create 2 instances of this class, but each instance is very lightweight and only has code for any differences between the 2 usages (i.e. the ContextMenu item might use `ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText`, while the ToolStrip item might use `ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image`).

This allows common code to exist only once inside your custom `MenuFeature` class, but still allows changes local to each usage of this menu item.

If you wanted to automatically synchronize properties like `Enabled`/`Visible`/etc, you could maintain a static collection of all instances inside the constructor, and then update all the items using events like `EnabledChanged`/etc.  I would recommend against this, however, as I've found different instances of the same menu 'feature' often need their own state - but this is getting out of scope on this Question, those interested in how I've managed items can comment on this answer or PM me.